# Bootstrap Scrollspy not working with Elm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, elm, scrollspy

I am using an `index.html` to include JavaScript such as jQuery and Bootstrap. Also, an Elm-Application gets injected into the `body`-node.
The entire view is then produced by Elm.

Within the new there is a Bootstrap-navigation which should include the scrollspy feature. It's just partially working as in that only the last possible target gets highlighted, no matter my position on the website.

Here's the index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Elm-Application</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- jQuery -->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>

    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="elm.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="page-top" class="index" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  </body>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    var elmApp = document.getElementById('page-top');
    app = Elm.Main.embed(elmApp,
      // The initial Model
      { location: "#"
      , width: window.innerWidth - 15
      , height: window.innerHeight
      , async_content: ""
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

My (shortened) Elm-app:

```
view =
    div []
        [ nav [ class "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ]
            [ div [ class "container" ]
                [ div [ class "navbar-header page-scroll" ]
                    [ button [ class "navbar-toggle", attribute "data-target" "#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1", attribute "data-toggle" "collapse", type' "button" ]
                        [ span [ class "sr-only" ]
                            [ text "Toggle navigation" ]
                        , span [ class "icon-bar" ]
                            []
                        , span [ class "icon-bar" ]
                            []
                        , span [ class "icon-bar" ]
                            []
                        ]
                    , a [ class "navbar-brand page-scroll", href "#page-top", onClick (Update.ClickedElem "#page-top") ]
                        [ text "Start Bootstrap" ]
                    ]
                , div [ class "collapse navbar-collapse", id "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" ]
                    [ ul [ class "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ]
                        [ li [ class "hidden" ]
                            [ a [ href "#page-top" ]
                                []
                            ]
                        , li []
                            [ a [ class "page-scroll", href "#services", onClick (Update.ClickedElem "#services") ]
                                [ text "Services" ]
                            ]
                        , li []
                            [ a [ class "page-scroll", href "#portfolio", onClick (Update.ClickedElem "#portfolio") ]
                                [ text "Portfolio" ]
                            ]
                        , li []
                            [ a [ class "page-scroll", href "#about", onClick (Update.ClickedElem "#about") ]
                                [ text "About" ]
                            ]
                        , li []
                            [ a [ class "page-scroll", href "#team", onClick (Update.ClickedElem "#team") ]
                                [ text "Team" ]
                            ]
                        , li []
                            [ a [ class "page-scroll", href "#contact", onClick (Update.ClickedElem "#contact") ]
                                [ text "Contact" ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                , text "  "
                ]
            ]
        , section [ id "contact" ]
            [-- More content
            ]
          -- Much more content
        , section [ id "contact" ]
            [-- More content
            ]
        ]


type alias Model =
    { location : String
    , height : Int
    , width : Int
    , async_content : String
    }


type Msg
    = ClickedElem String

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd.Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        _ ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

In the end, when launching the website, only the `li` with the href of `#contact` gets highlighted, no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the Elm-code, but rather with the HTML-code.
I forgot the `doctype` declaration in the very beginning.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of just `<html>` fixed it for me!
Thanks to Curt and his answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348841/3686898